# Is there a reason the British omit the article when they "go to hospital"?

Tags: nouns, british-english, articles, definite-articles, syntactic-analysis

Why do British speakers omit the article in constructions like "go to hospital" or "go on holiday"? Pretty much all American speakers would rephrase those as "go to *the* hospital" and "go on *a* holiday", I think. Is there any good reason, or forgotten sense behind those words that might explain why the articles are ommitted?  Are there other common constructions other than those two that the British use that drop the article?

---

I just realized per Kosmonaut's comment that Americans do much the same thing with a few nouns, so this isn't all that special.   Do grammaticists designate nouns that can have their article dropped with anything, i.e. do they have anything in common?

Comment: We Americans say "go to school", "go to work", "go to college", and "go on vacation". Brits just do one or two more.

Comment: Correction: Americans don't say _go on a holiday_: we say _go on vacation_.

Comment: I'm British, and I've never said "go to hospital" - sounds strange to me. Some of the others are familiar though.

Comment: @UpTheCreek: I'm English and it's perfectly normal. Are you from Corby or something?!

Comment: COCA has significantly fewer instances of "to hospital" as BNC (I haven't checked how many of them are actually the construction at issue), but it does have a good number. @UpTheCreek, both the en-gb and en-us examples seem to favour "taken" or "rushed to hospital" over "go".

Comment: Kind of related: I've always wondered why Americans omit 'of' in places so  that, for example, "a couple of people" would become "a couple people".

Comment: @billynomates: I don't think that that's related.

Comment: @Tomalak It's related in that it is about Americans omitting words from sentences.

Comment: @billynomates: And I think it's unrelated in that it's about omitting words for different reasons. See my answer where I explain that, context-dependent, the "of" can be omitted in English, too.

Comment: @Tomalak -  Perfectly normal for you perhaps.  No I'm not from Corby.

Comment: @Peter Taylor:Yes, I agree.  'Go into hospital' is another possibility.

Comment: @UpTheCreek, I didn't offer any opinions with which to agree or disagree. Just some summarised observations from corpora.

Comment: Looking at the discussions below it seems that BE is consistent and it is AmE that has the exceptions.

Comment: Also, we don't say "holiday" like that, you're talking about a vacation, while a holiday is a nationally recognized day for celebration, like Christmas, or Halloween, or Thanksgiving.

Comment: @billynomates except this is about british people omitting words, not Americans.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I can't speak for AmE, but in British English there is a distinction between "to school" and "to the school". If you say:

> He went to school/church/hospital.

you imply that they went there for 'the purpose for which that place is designed'. On the other hand, if you say:

> Jimmy's parents went to *the* school to meet the headmaster.
>
> He wasn't religious, but he went to *the* church to help with the flower arranging.
>
> With a bottle of arsenic in his pocket, he went to *the* hospital to visit his sick wealthy mother-in-law.

it implies that they went there as a visitor and not for the actual purpose of the building in question.

Comment: As an AmE speaker, I do the same thing for school/church, just not for 'hospital'.

Comment: Another one: soldiers go to war, while reporters go to the war zone.

Comment: Thanks Neil! I love it when someone points something like that. It's amazing how many of us manage to implement the distinction *exactly* as you so succinctly put it, without being conciously aware even of the existence of a rule, let alone exactly how to formulate it.

Comment: @Neil Coffey So, if I'm understanding you correctly, if you described someone as "going to hospital" in British English, that would carry the implication that they are sick in some way?

Comment: @Billare: yes, although the preposition would usually be "into" with "go". So either "he's going into hospital" or "he's in hospital" implies that the person is ill.

Comment: Yet people "go to bed" when they want to sleep, they don't "go bed." Does this rule only apply to buildings?

Comment: No, it just applies to a few places where there is a notion that you "regularly stay/attend there for a specific purpose" and/or where the place is 'institutionalised': "school", "college", "university", "church", "prison", "borstal", "hospital", "day care (centre)" or where there's a crossover between the name of a place and name of activity: "he went to Sunady school/gym class/Summer camp". But you wouldn't say "*He went to bank every Tuesday", "*They went to concert hall at weekends".

Comment: @Neil Coffey, _He went to bank every Tuesday_ is wrong the way you meant it but fine if one reads _bank_ as a verb. (Just nitpicking, not disagreeing with your point.)

Comment: Well yeah I suppose so, just about.

Comment: @DanielT.: "Bed" *is* actually a perfect example of this phenomenon: we say "go to bed" (for sleeping) instead of "go to the bed" (to, say, pick up something that lying on it). This is even though "bed" in every other context is used with the article: we don't say "here is bed" or "it's on bed", for instance.

Comment: This answer deserves at least 200 upvotes.

Comment: Even though this is an old thread I want to voice my agreement with @jbelacqua. As an AmE speaker also, I say/hear "to school/church" but NEVER hear an AmE speaker say "to hospital". Even though your examples using "the" apply to AmE as well, "hospital" in the other case, never stands alone.  However, we can see that BE is uniform and AmE has the exceptions.

Comment: They went to cemetery?

Comment: @TimRomano But *he went to heaven*!

Comment: @TRomano People whose goal is a cemetery, for the purpose which cemeteries are built for, rarely go there on their own. ;-)

Comment: Peter Shor's example is different - 'war' is a verb there, the soldiers are going to do warring. Reporters are not, so obviously they go to report on 'the war' from 'the war zone' etc.

Answer (score 33):

When we omit the article before the noun, we are thinking of a  state or condition, not of a specific place:  in jail, in love, in hospital, at university, under fire,

Comment: How can you possibly be under fire?

Comment: @MarcusJ It’s a state of being most commonly found in soldiers and police officers.

Comment: @MarcusJ To add, if you're "under fire" it's because you're ducking down to the ground while bullets fly over. You are literally under the horizontal direction of firing guns.

Comment: Ahh yeah I didn't think about that, good example.

Answer (score 8):

How we refer to roads is a an example where the reverse is true (in some parts of the US). Brits might say *Take the M1* or *Take the A1*, while most Americans will say *take 95* or *take 81*. In Southern California, however, people say, *take the 101* or *the 1*.

Comment: as an aside, I think it's interesting to note when someone who lives in Hollywood is writing a show about D.C. for example, and mentions _the_ 95.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think it's the entire Western US where this happens, just Southern California. I lived in the San Francisco area growing up, and I was surprised by this when I first visited LA (around 1980). Also, in Washington D.C. you would say "take the Beltway" (part of which is 95).

Comment: Both can be mixed in the same location too. In Ontario we take the 401 to Toronto (a major freeway) but we take 15 to Smith's Falls (a two-lane highway). The latter is often said take highway 15.

Comment: Check out the EL&U question on this topic, _[US Route 101 - “The 101”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15771/5822)_. And also [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6514/differences-between-american-dialects/6515#6515).

Comment: I'm from Chicago, and we always omit the "the" before road names. I've always thought it's because they're proper names - for the same reason you wouldn't say, "take the Emmy to school", you wouldn't say, "take the Lincoln Highway to the I57."

Comment: I can see reasons for saying "the" or omitting it. In your second example Lincoln is an adjective. You would say take the Highway, rather than Take Highway.

Comment: @Wayne We say "take the 401" but we also say "take highway 401", not "take the highway 401". The "the" is based on the presence of "highway"; the rule is consistent.

Comment: @PeterShor But we do *go by road/rail/sea/air*. However, during the journey we are *on the road/sea* and *in the air/train*.

Answer (score 8):

There is a distinction.

- "I went to the hospital" describes the act of physically visiting the physical hospital building. "I went to hospital" describes the wider act of having been infirmed and gone to the hospital building, possibly with a stay, and having been seen by a nurse/doctor.
- Similarly, "he just got out of the hospital" implies that "he" has stepped out of the building, possibly having popped into the hospital shop for a lottery ticket; "he just got out of hospital" says that "he" has been discharged and is probably feeling much better.
- "I went to the school" describes the act of physically visiting the physical building, whereas "I went to school" talks about the wider act of having spent the day in an educational institution learning from your teachers.

You could mix and match them, but it's quite common to *leave out the article* in what is the more common case.

Comment: But to omit the article with hospital, I believe implies an overnight stay. If I had a day appointment at the hospital (in Britain), my wife might say to the neighbour *he has gone to the hospital to have his arm x-rayed*. Were she to say *he's gone to hospital* it might suggest at least the possibility of being kept in overnight.

Comment: @WS2: Hmm not necessarily I don't think. I can see where you're coming from... but, if I trip and fall and get a nasty cut on my head, they might take me to hospital ... even if I'm out in an hour.

Comment: Yes. If it were an emergency I agree - *to hospital* one would go. But any procedure that your doctor could not perform might have to be done *at the hospital*. But where would you have more complicated surgery - *in hospital* of course.

Comment: @WS2: mmmmm maybe it's the "at" vs "in" that does it. You can be in the state of being hospitalised but not _at_ that state. But you can of course be at or in _the_ hospital as much as you like :) (well, until security ejects you I suppose)

Comment: You certainly have an appointment *at the hospital*, not *at hospital*. But people say *Will you have to stay in*? - meaning *in hospital*. Yes I think *at* is more likely to attract the article. But your doctor could still say *it will have to be done at hospital*.

Comment: @WS2: That sounds weird to me. But with the recent influx of non-English-speaking doctors, I agree it is certainly conceivable! ;)

Answer (score 5):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:in_the_hospital) has an archived discussion on the issue, though it's from a lexicography viewpoint (does the phrase belong in a dictionary?).

> Also, are there other common constructions other than those two that the British use that drop the article?

*In hospital* and *at uni*.

Also, (I'm pretty sure both Brits and) Americans use *in bed*, *in school*, *in church*, and *in class*.

Comment: But you would say; in the bedroom, in the classroom. Don't know if there is a general underlying rule

Comment: I don't know if it's a rule or not, but in the bedroom, or in the classroom, refer specifically to a place. In bed, or in class, is a state of being. You could be in class on the quad lawn, for example.

Comment: @EmmyS And *in jail* means you are a prisoner. But prison officers do not work *in jail* but *at the jail*.

Answer (score 2):

Incidentally, there is a distinction between going *into* / *in* hospital (implies admission, and some length of stay that's pre-planned) and going *to* hospital (implies only a brief stay, usually to accident and emergency).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the point in your edit, is true.

For your main question, the answer is simple. It is not necessary to say "go to the hospital" or "go on the holiday", when talking in a general sense. Use of the word 'the', means that the sentence is in a particular sense. A reference to one, particular example. "go to the hospital" will mean going to one, particular hospital.

If what you mean is going to a hospital generally, for example talking about an injury that happened to you many years ago and an ambulance was called; then saying "the hospital", will have a different meaning.

I noticed that it is Americans who will speak like that. This sounds odd and unnecessary to me, as a British person. I have not heard any British people speak like that.

This can cause misunderstanding. I remember an example of this, when I was talking to an American friend. They mentioned an incident in which their neighbour had an accident and an ambulance was called. They said the neighbour was taken "to the hospital" and came home the next day. I asked which hospital and they stopped talking for a moment. They looked confused and asked why I would ask that, considering that I don't live near them and therefore would not be familiar with it. After explaining that this not how British people speak, they realised.

If what you mean is one, particular example, like going to a particular hospital or a particular school that you have referred to by name; then, saying "going to the hospital" or "going to the school', will make sense.

Basically, the word 'the', is not necessary in sentences that are in the general sense. The, is used when referring to something in a particular sense.

Comment: A perfect example of what you discussed above, I guess, could be a part of what you've written as your profile i.e. "... and sharing the benefit of my experience as a speaker of THE English of England, UK.

Answer (score 1):

One facet of this that is confusing in American English is that you can go “to college”, but you are never “at university”, you are “at a university” and also “at college”. I have no idea why this is the case or is acceptable.

I’ve seen this with the previously mentioned “at uni”, “at hospital” and “in future”.

Since “the future” is a place (like a hospital or a university”and a time, I find this rather odd.

Comment: At least in BE 'at university' is perfectly normal 'at a U..' is odd

Comment: You say "at least", but you are at "a" specific University, just like you drive a car to the office.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have time to complete my edit: You say "at least", but you are at "a" specific University, just like you drive "a" car to the office.  I'm interested in why there is a perceived difference between the two.  The "university" is not a proper name (which is how we are taught in the US), so by our logic and instruction, there should be an article in front of it.

Comment: The 'at least' meant my claim was only about BE not AE. In BE you would say "I am at University" to say you are studying, or "I am at XYZ" to specify which university. I can't think of a case where you would naturally say "I am at A university". You generally leave out the 'a' for places which are also a 'state' so in hospital/in prison/at university - describe being in a certain state 'ill/locked-up/studying" rather than the building

Comment: Never a strong word.