# Does one apply "to university" or "to a university"?

Tags: grammaticality, articles

Is one of these more correct?

> I will apply to university next year.
>
> I will apply to a university next year.

Also:

> I go to university.
>
> I go to a university.

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: It's given in my spot the error exercise,precisely on usage of articles.

Comment: I think US and UK are opposite on this.

Comment: In the US we would say college so "I go to college" is the same as "I go to university" in the UK.  I think it has to do with the fact that our football is better....

Comment: Related: [Is there a reason the British omit the article when they “go to hospital”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital) Also, please see (and follow) our [guidelines for asking homework questions](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/333/how-to-deal-with-homework-questions/346#346).

Comment: If the question is - What do you do?
Then the answer - "I go to college" is just fine.

Comment: @RegDwight: Why do you think "homework questions" is relevant here? I've already learnt something from this Q, in that I didn't conciously realise that US usage habitually includes "a" where Brits say "to university/hospital(/etc.?)". So I certainly can't agree with nohat's implication that the Q is pointless.

Comment: Americans may "attend a university" but they typically "go to college".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: since this is a homework question, the guidelines for asking homework questions are relevant by definition.

Comment: @RegDwight: My mistake, sorry. I didn't notice OP's explanatory comment. It seems lamentable in the extreme that anyone should be setting homework questions where the "correct" answer largely depends on whether you favour British or American usage.

Comment: Presumably this question occurs in the UK or the US, and there was some reading material assigned in advance to explain it.  But it **does** show that this international site is not the best place to get answers for your homeowork.

Comment: @RegDwight:This was not my homework,I was just inquisitive.

Comment: @GEdgar: Only a bad teacher would deliberately choose to focus on syntax where US/UK usage differs, and in my opinion only an even worse one would do it accidentally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nice to find a usage where the Brits are [ahead of the curve](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/english-idioms-sayings/20256-ahead-curve.html) for once (I went **to university**, obviously – as did most UK undergraduates by the mid 60s).
[image]

Americans have been slower to adopt the new usage, but they're getting there...
[image]

As implied by *@M. Tibbits's* answer and comments thereto, I think including "a" implies slightly more "exclusivity/cachet/prestige", notwithstanding that many Americans will say "university" means the same as "college" (US speakers *go to college*, just as in the UK we *go to university*). I suggest that Brits are following this principle when they speak of *going to* **a** *redbrick [university]*.

Comment: No, they aren't. **Nobody** says that in the USA. If you try saying "to University" here, you will get "corrected". What your graphs are probably showing is a rise in the relative number of UK/Austrialian/Indian(?) graduates.

Comment: @T.E.D.: The American educational system would indeed be in a perilous state if the (I'd have thought, tiny, out of 1.5M) proportion of UK/Austrialian/Indian graduates could effect such a linguistic change. I take it you don't deny "go to college" and "go to school" are valid in the US. I think it is an absolute certainty US usage will switch to that form as degree-level education becomes more widespread, but you are of course welcome to your opinion on that, as well as the validity of NGram figures and trends.

Comment: Your prediction may well be right (my crystal ball is on the fritz). However, I can say for a fact that right now "go to University" is not used in American English, and would be considered incorrect. So as it stands today, this is a regionalism.

Comment: On a less relevant note, if BritEnglish speakers get to throw in the folks from India on this, it doesn't take much to swamp us poor AVE speakers. A 2004 census study I found claimed India had about 50 million graduates, a number which had doubled since the previous decade. The USA has around 116 million graduates (including 2 year associate degrees, which may or may not count). With over a billion people, one day we will all be speaking the Indian dialect of English. :-)

Comment: @T.E.D.: It's your language, not mine, so you're welcome to excoriate any of your countrymen you think are precipitately moving to the new usage. I haven't offered any opinions as to "correct/incorrect" usage either side of the pond. I'm just pointing out what people actually say, with particular reference to the fact that *the most common* usage seems to have switched for *all* speakers, so it's not "just" a standard US/UK difference dating from Webster, like *colour/color*.

Comment: ...I did actually check US degree statistics purely to see if the ratio of graduates to general population was similar to UK. I found there were 1.3M US graduates in 2007. My degree not being in maths, I'm having trouble scaling that up to your 116M in total.

Comment: I don't correct people's spoken English unless they ask. However, in this case nobody really has to excoriate anyone, because nobody here in the US ever says that. (We also don't ever say "Maths" btw.)

Comment: Google ngrams results for the phrases [go to college,go to university](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=go+to+college%2Cgo+to+university&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that usage of "go to college" totally swamps usage of "go to university". Presumably skewed by many U.S. English results.

Comment: @Firstrock: On your own NGram link, if you just restrict the view to "British English", this will confirm your assumption. But in fact, Brits say "go to college" far more often in recent years - partly copying Americans, partly because more of our recent tertiary educational establishments aren't actually universities, and partly because NGrams is far from perfect in distinguishing British/American usage.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is more *American* (as per FF's answer below) to use 'a' before the common noun 'university'.  But if it were replaced with a proper noun, the use of 'a' is incorrect.

Hence:

```
I go to Cambridge.
I go to a university.
```

And similarly:

```
I will apply to Cambridge. 
I will apply to a university.  (only one?)
```

Comment: I don't really think "correct" is the right word here. Per Chad's comment, Americans have traditionally gone to college anyway. Today it would probably sound 'provincial' to speak of having gone to **a** college if the particular college isn't relevant. Dropping the **a** with universities isn't 'wrong', it's just an emerging usage.

Comment: Sounds quite reasonable.  Editing to that effect.

Comment: Agreed that "correct" isn't the right word. The answer is pretty simple really: Its an American vs. British English issue.

Comment: Incidentally, I and my four siblings all "went to university" (being British, obviously). Probably all of them have said to me somewhen since "Ah, but I went to a *university*!", because my particular educational establishment changed from being a *polytechnic* to a *university* while I was a student.

Answer (score 1):

The ones with "a" are definitely acceptable in American English. The ones without sound British to me... though we'd also say "go to school" and "go to college", "go to university" isn't as common an idiom.

Answer (score 1):

In Australia, I would find "I go to a university" a bit awkward. "I go to university" would be overwhelmingly more common, as would "I'm at university". "I go to a university" sounds like the speaker is making a point that they only attend one one, or that a university is an unusual thing. It almost sounds like they're being enigmatic about which one they are attending, perhaps because it isn't very prestigious.

Comment: I think you've got a key point there - using "a" implies that *a university is an unusual thing*. I suspect that even though in principle *college/university* are equivalent in the US, the latter term has [had?] more 'cachet'. How many US institutions have changed their identity from *university* to *college* in recent decades (not counting those being absorbed into a larger institution)? I bet more have changed from *college* to *university* - because it sounds better, perhaps.

Comment: Interestingly, Australia has never used the word 'college' as an equal of university. College is a vague term that might mean 'matriculation college' (ie years 11 and 12 pre-university) or 'technical college' (where you learn a trade rather than a profession).

Comment: Yes, it's much the same in the UK. In fact, the university I went to was originally called a polytechnic. I do think today's UK degrees are worth less than they were decades ago - but that's probably just the grumpy ole man in me coming out a bit ahead of his time! :)

Comment: In Tasmania, our government has just renamed our 'matriculation colleges' as 'academies' and our technical colleges as 'polytechnics'. (I think, it's so hard to keep up.)

Comment: @fumbleFingers: in the US, people frequently interchange the words "college" and "university" in casual conversation, largely because people don't always feel the need to be pedantic (and also because one does attend a college at university), but institutions do not "interchange them for identity" because a university is a grouping of colleges. If they changed the name it is probably because they have merged with or added a college.

Comment: @horatio: Umm. I did know that US universities often contain colleges. It's the same in the UK. But we also have lots of establishments called 'colleges' that are nowehere near that level (similar to Australia as per *Richard A* above). That's why I put the caveat that US 'unis' probably rarely rename themselves 'colleges' *unless* they're being absorbed into a larger uni.

Comment: To confuse things further, our universities are made up of faculties, but not colleges. When I was at university, being 'in college' meant that you were living at one of the residential colleges that have no academic function.