# What's the general rule for dropping articles in article & section titles or in figure & table captions?

Tags: articles, titles, headline-english

[It is said](https://davidappleyard.com/english-article-usage.html) that "To give added punch, articles are often dropped in the titles of books, movies, music, and other works of art" and "To save space and boost impact, articles are usually dropped in headlines."

Source: [David Appleyard's English Language Help Site](https://davidappleyard.com/index.html)

Is there any general rule or reference about dropping articles, especially in academic research papers?

Comment: It might help if you gave an example sentence where you're not sure which usage is prefered.

Comment: I voted to migrate this to Writers. I think this type of question is more about writing style than grammatical correctness.

Comment: @jsv _Save a file back to disk_ is not a title. The bounty is offered on the wrong question.

Comment: @JK2 Well, I know it's not a title but more a caption. But I suppose this question is actually about headlinese in general and not just titles. Headlinese is used for newspaper headlines as well as for book titles and figure/caption captions. There is no real difference where we use it. Its "logic" and "rules" are the same, I suppose. Well, I'm foreigner, so I might be wrong, of course.

Comment: Academic titles are not titles of news articles. Very simple.

Comment: If we're going in for a large bounty and academic papers and image captions have already been brought up, it would be helpful to also touch on the similar shortening of encyclopedia headings (Britannica, Wikipedia, etc.) if there are any major differences.

Answer (score 14):

Omitting an article (definite or indefinite) in a newspaper title is done for brevity and in order to attract more attention. There are some rules regarding titles (and they basically apply to newspapers and magazines and not to research journals). Firstly, usually **Simple Present** is used regardless of the time position of the action (which is usually in the past). Elaborating a bit more on the use of tenses, titles like "Egypt and Israel Move to Halt Growth of Crisis" (in The Herald Tribune, International) are quite interesting as the **infinitive** form "to halt" yields a shorter title.

Regarding articles, you may drop them as soon as the meaning remains clear. An example from "The Times, UK" is the title : "Fees will create class of stay-at-home students" while usually one would say "...a class...". The newspaper "Daily Mail, UK" on the other hand, in which journalists are not sparing with titles' length, you find titles like "How the rebels planned assault on Tripoli: Call to arms for 'sleeper cells' came from mosques". So it is more like a "rule of thumb" rather than a grammar rule.

In scientific papers in particular you can be more explicit and usually articles are not dropped.

Comment: Does this also apply to things like email subjects and git commit messages?

Comment: I upvoted it, **but:** _"Regarding articles, you may drop them as soon as the meaning remains clear."_ - The current examples don't reflect the fact that it's quite common to see a title that drops one article, but preserves the other one. E.g., the definite article in the very beginning of the title is omitted, but the definite article in the middle of the same title is preserved.

Comment: "...the infinitive form to halt yields a shorter title...": Er, no it doesn't, in any way. "Move to Halt Growth of" is a very roundabout way of saying "Limit" or "Try to Limit", intended to work in the idea that some crisis is growing despite both Israelis & Arabs' best efforts. It's not bad writing (from newsmen's panic-maximizing POV), but it doesn't remotely reflect the point you're trying to make.

Comment: @lly  In the headline,  *to halt* would be  short for something like "are currently negotiating to cease the growing conflict."

Comment: @Mari-LouA Pull the other one. That's one longer paraphrase of the entire predicate (not _to halt_); I've already provided a much shorter one. Neither has anything to do with the helpfulness of infinitives in headlines. Overall, it's an adequate answer. That part of it remains nonsensical and the answer would be improved if it were corrected or removed.

Comment: @lly Nothing **nonsensical** about that part, I think it was quite good and there'a a significant difference in meaning between  "limit (the) crisis" and "move to halt growth of crisis” the former may be shorter but it conveys less meaning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Only in the sense of shading the crisis as more menacing and hence better for newspaper sales. The actual action is the same. In any case, it remains nonsensical: the infinitive has nothing to do with shortening anything, as your poor example above (which again draws in the entire predicate) illustrates.

Comment: @lly the actual action is **not** the same. "Limit growth" is a superset of "halt growth" - in fact halting narrows it down to only the most extreme edge cases of limiting (total limiting, with the suggestion of it being basically immediate as opposed to gradual). You would be throwing out all that possibility-narrowing meaning if you used "limit" (and this is significant/important meaning if it accurately reflects the parties taking actions which actually intend or are likely to succeed at a total and quick stop of growth rather than mere slowing of growth rate).

Comment: @lly furthermore, omitting "growth" also expands possible meaning: there is far more to a conflict than just growth, and in fact if they just "limited" the conflict (rather than growth of) the conflict, I would think they might have for example limited some aspect of it (how the conflict effects refugees/civilians) while still permitting the conflict to grow, or deescalated rather than merely not escalating, or possibly decided to just stop the conflict entirely (limit the damage/harm to what has happened already). By having "growth" in there they scope it to just limiting escalation.

Comment: @lly lastly, having "move to" in there makes it clear that they have not already succeeded/finished, and in fact suggests that they've merely only started or are even only about to start. "Egypt and Israel (Limit/Halt) [Growth of] Conflict" could be (and probably is) reporting the successful result of their actions - "Egypt and Israel Move to (Limit/Halt) [Growth of] Conflict" unambiguously reports that they have only begun to act towards that goal.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than exact rules, you will find some guidelines for omitting articles in titles and headlines. More often, articles about writing a good title for a  journal paper or article talk about *conciseness in general*. Knowing exactly *which* articles can be safely omitted can be tricky. I suggest finding published articles with as similar a subject matter as possible and using those titles as models.

> Articles are usually omitted in titles and headlines to save space and
> boost impact. *[How to Use Articles in Academic Writing](https://www.enago.com/academy/article-usage-in-academic-writing/)*

> Articles are generally omitted in titles and headlines for conciseness
> and directness. [How To Use Articles In Academic Writing](https://www.trinka.ai/blog/how-to-use-articles-in-academic-writing/)

The OP asks about the articles in this instance:

> "The current example doesn't mention cases in which one of the
> articles is dropped and another one is not. For example, a line from
> the official Emacs reference card: "Save **a** file back **to disk**: C-x
> C-s". Why the first article is kept, but the second one, before the
> word "disk", is omitted?
> (gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/pdf/refcard.pdf)

The article is omitted here not to save space, but because the instruction is referring to a general category (all instances), rather than a specific instance.

> WHEN NOT TO USE ARTICLES Non-native English writers commonly either
> omit or overuse articles. Articles are not always necessary. Articles
> are generally not used when referring to an entire category, such as
> education, patience, music, etc. That is "Music enhances learning"
> instead of "The music enhances learning."  [SciTechEdit](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=Paging%2C%20on%20the%20other%20hand%2C%20is%20the%20process%20of%20moving%20one%20or%20usually%20a%20related%20cluster%20of%20pages%20from%20disk%20to%20memory%20%28paging%20in%29%20or%20from%20memory%20to%20disk)

> Paging, on the other hand, is the process of moving one or usually
> **a** related cluster of pages **from disk to memory** (paging in) or  **from memory to disk** ( paging out). [ref](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=Paging%2C%20on%20the%20other%20hand%2C%20is%20the%20process%20of%20moving%20one%20or%20usually%20a%20related%20cluster%20of%20pages%20from%20disk%20to%20memory%20%28paging%20in%29%20or%20from%20memory%20to%20disk)

> Caching
> There is a large disparity between **the** time it takes to write
> **to memory** and **the** time it takes to write **to disk**. [ref](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Caching%20There%20is%20a%20large%20disparity%20between%20the%20time%20it%20takes%20to%20write%20to%20memory%20and%20the%20time%20it%20takes%20to%20write%20to%20disk%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk00eLVYRbEyXx0l2NDq8Dhd9BzF9MA%3A1627834432983&ei=QMgGYYPBO9i0tAbB44aACA&oq=%22Caching%20There%20is%20a%20large%20disparity%20between%20the%20time%20it%20takes%20to%20write%20to%20memory%20and%20the%20time%20it%20takes%20to%20write%20to%20disk%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2697.4760.0.12037.3.3.0.0.0.0.74.74.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0....0.Dh6eevwZpm8)

> The former refers **to processes** moved from disk **to memory**, whereas
> the latter corresponds **to processes** moved from memory **to disk**.  [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Performance_by_Design/sxE931Medm4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22The%20former%20refers%20to%20processes%20moved%20from%20disk%20to%20memory,%20whereas%20the%20latter%22&pg=PA158&printsec=frontcover)

*Read/reading from disk/memory* and *write/writing to disk/memory* are the standard, idiomatic phrases used for computers.

In the first example above, the **a** *related cluster of pages* refers to a/any given cluster, whereas *to memory* and *to disk* are being conventionally used as a category without reference to any specific memory/disk. We see something similar with a *Note/Memo to File* used, for example, in a research trial to document something (e.g. conduct). We're interested in the documentation and not the specific physical file where the note is kept (usually a paper file in this case).

Note that *processes* has no article in the last example. These are processes in general.

In the case of a plural, ask yourself whether it is being used as a category or for specific instances. If you can replace *the* with *these/those,* it usually means the article is necessary:

*Animals can be dangerous.* (Animals in general; the category)

*Be careful! The animals can be dangerous.* (*These animals...* or the animals I was talking about.)

*Cold water can make for an invigorating shower.* Cold water in general.

*The cold water was only one reason we gave the inn a bad review.* Specific--the cold water (only) that came out of their shower.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, DjinTonic.

Answer (score 4):

The particular context of "To give added punch" is about movie/book titles. That's really an aspect of [marketese](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=marketese&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=rk5RTsOHK5Sn8QOVp4zNBw&sqi=2&ved=0CBgQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=476c7489afd8cad7&biw=1376&bih=888), which probably has little to do with OP's question.

In general, I think [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital) (about *in [the] hospital*) shows that there are no hard-and-fast rules, but sometimes there are cases where standard usage differs between US and UK.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native speaker, but my teachers have taught me not to use any articles in titles. However, I am not completely sure that this is a general rule. I am translating a text about a faculty now and I feel that articles are just needed...if we speak about fees, professors, etc. I feel like putting THE over and over again, because we think of a specific faculty.. What is more, I believe it is okay to omit articles in newspapers, because we want the news to be short and shocking, but in some other places, a word more or less does not make a big deal.