# Articles a/the in the captions of photos or title of the books/movies

Tags: articles

It is not really clear for me how should I translate captions for photos. For example, I made photo of bear and the caption should be "A Bear" or "The Bear" or just "Bear"? The same thing for "Autumn","Duck Family", "Regatta","Blossom", Spring Snow, Reflection, Old Lion, Morning Alley etc.
I know the general rule how to choose a/the articles when they used in conversation or any other text. But in caption/title it is little bit different and confusing. The caption or title in most cases describes something new for a reader, and as consequence, you cannot use THE, so it must be the A article. But for example name of the movie "The Omen". Why it is THE there? I didn't see the movie, so as I reader, I don't know what about this movie. So logically it should be "An Omen". the same thing for "The Terminator" for example. Also when you look at the photo, you already see and understand what is about. So title of photo can have THE. THE BEAR - means THAT BEAR, on the photo, not any other bear. Am I right?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: "The Bear" would be wrong unless it was a particular bear.  But "A Bear" and "Bear" would be silly since everyone who sees the picture knows that it's a bear.  How about "The bear that nearly ate me during my vacation"?  Really, it's your album, so you can put what you want.

Comment: "A omen" would be wrong in any case, because before vowel sounds, the article *an* is used, never *a*.

Comment: This is a closer duplicate, in case the marked duplicate is not helpful: [Dropping articles in the title (of an article or a section) or in the caption (of a figure or a table)? What's the general rule?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/38759/53711)