# "To market, to market, to buy a fresh pig" vs "To the markets" valid English?

Tags: idioms, grammatical-number, articles

Is the phrase "to market" as in "going to the markets" valid use of the English language?

I can think of two examples in local Australian vernacular:

1. The Nursery Rhyme:
   "To market, to market, to buy a fresh pig"

   [Going to the markets, to the markets, to buy a fresh pig]
2. An advertising jingle:
   "You haven't been to market until you've been to Paddy's"

   [You have been to an authentic markets until you've been to Paddy's]

Or this is just an historic use of the English language that we never lost?

Comment: Is the problem you see with 'the' or with the plural 'markets'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: I believe the essence of your question has been answered, and very effectively so, on StackExchange [already](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital). The following is merely my take on how that explanation applies specifically to the phrase "to market".*

Note that in the case of "to market" it is actually logical for both sellers and buyers to use that phrase since a market has both buying and selling as its main purpose.

In the case of a hospital, the main purpose is to treat patients (and not to provide a working place for doctors and nurses) and thus a patient would go "to hospital" while a doctor would go "to the hospital".

Answer (score 2):

There are some contexts in which an article doesn’t appear where you might expect one. The effect, as with *market*, is to give the noun an abstract, universal sense. Such cases are said to be 'anarthrous'. Other words where this feature can occur are *congress, conference, counsel, parliament, hospital, school* and *college*. For further discussion, see [here](http://realgrammar.posterous.com/absent-article)  and [here](http://realgrammar.posterous.com/more-on-articles).