# Usage of the word 'The'

Tags: grammar

I was recently speaking with a non-native English speaker and they asked me a question as to when we use the word 'the'.

EX: I will see you in the class vs I will see you in class. Is there a rule as to why the latter sounds more natural.

Comment: Depending on context, either is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do American English and British English use the definite article differently?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67036/how-do-american-english-and-british-english-use-the-definite-article-differently) (see MT_Head's answer; 'in class' means 'when we are in a lesson '; 'in the class' means you both know which lesson it will be and are referring to that lesson.