# At school vs in school

Tags: phrases, prepositions, articles

I am confused between these two

1. Our teachers were not in the school yesterday
2. Our teachers were not at school yesterday

Similarly

1. My mother was in the temple yesterday evening
2. My mother was at the temple yesterday evening

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["In school" vs "at school"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63772/in-school-vs-at-school)

Comment: Also https://english.stackexchange.com/q/67036/191178

Comment: Still  lil bit confused what is the best case in these two scenarios

Comment: It partly depends on whether you want to speak American or British English.