# "Go on excursion" vs. "go on an excursion"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, indefinite-articles

Is it grammatical to say, "The class is going on excursion"? My thought is that it would be preferable to say "The class is going on an excursion".

My colleague thinks that the first sentence is correct. What do you think?

Comment: Related: [Is there a reason the British omit the article when they “go to hospital”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital)

Comment: Going to hospital is not the same as going on excursion. The latter is not common in BrE.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: True, but our politicians *go walkabout*, they don't *go **on** walkabout*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think I disagree.  Australian aborigines *go walkabout* and remain lost for months or years: politicans *go on a walkabout* (though if they want to go walkabout, that's fine by me).

Comment: @TimLymington: I'm not sure what you're disagreeing about. I know *go walkabout* is also used with that specialised sense for aborigines - my point was that it's very "non-standard" to speak of anyone *"going **on** walkabout"*. Some prepositional usages, such as OP's here, are "uncommon, but reasonably acceptable to many". Many other "plausible" usages simply don't occur.

Answer (score 1):

While “The class is going on excursion” sounds fine to me, it appears that  “... on an excursion” is a more-common form.  An [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+excursion%2Con+an+excursion%2Con+journey%2Con+trip&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for *on excursion,on an excursion,on journey,on trip* shows that *on an excursion* is hundreds of times more frequent than *on excursion*. Note that the percentage of *relevant* instances among instances of *on an excursion* is high, and the percentage of *relevant* instances among instances of *on excursion* is low, which changes the ratio to thousands of times instead of merely hundreds.  That is, if you inspect [book links](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20excursion%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) for *on excursion*, most are irrelevant; for example, refer to passengers on excursion steamers rather than to passengers on excursions.

Among the book links, you may find the link to Martin Haspelmath's [Coordinating Constructions](http://books.google.com/books?id=FxkobNpxQhwC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=%22on+excursion%22&source=bl&ots=vit2wTHQUy&sig=P8Jvkxp3GoGACba6vVor1RBA4LQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fDNTUOvqJpHqiQLa8oCYAQ&ved=0CGQQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22on%20excursion%22&f=false) of interest, as it specifically treats the *on excursion, on an excursion* pair, albeit via examples translated from Polish.  Part of what he says is not profound: some coordinating conjunction uses are constrained syntactically; some are constrained semantically; and some are constrained both ways.  I don't know if the rest of what he says (re non-reflexive possessive pronouns vs reflexive pronouns) is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a UK/US thing. In the US, "going on excursion" would definitely be considered a grammar error. "Excursion" is a noun, and when used in the singular it calls for an article. (Or a similar adjective: You could say, "The class went on one excursion this semester.")

I understand "go to hospital" is common in the UK, while in the US we always say "go to THE hospital". Though we do say "go to work" and "go to school" with no articles. I don't know if there's some rule to explain that or if those are just special cases.