# Being 'admitted' to the hospital?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, nouns

Does one say "Hospitalization/hospitalized" when it comes to staying at the hospital because you're sick?

Or is it "I'm being admitted at the hospital"?

And If I was compiling a statistic of people going in and out of the hospital, could I say "entries" and "leaves"?

Comment: By the way I have found an interesting article: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hospitalization* is more often used to record or count times people are *hospitalized*.

> How many *hospitalizations* were uninsured last year?

It could be used to describe ones own hospital stay, but is infrequent.

> I had three *hospitalizations* in a two month span.

More frequently, one would say

> I was hospitalized three times in two months.

*Hospitalize* (and its past tense, *hospitalized*) is commonly used both to describe ones own hospital stay as well as those of others

> I was *hospitalized* for asthma last year.
>   We had to *hospitalize* him after a fall.

The verb *to admit* is also regularly used both describing oneself and others.

> I was *admitted* to the hospital.
>   They *admitted* him to the hospital for a broken leg.

Entry into a hospital is usually called an *admission*. Departure from a hospital is usually called a *discharge*. Both noun and verb forms are used.

> I was *admitted* to the hospital.
>   It's an emergency; *admit* the patient now.
>   There were several *admissions* to the hospital today for flu.
>   She was *discharged* immediately after the operation.
>   I will *discharge* the patient when his fever goes down.
>   Her *discharge* was followed by a *readmission* for infection.

NOTE: The use of the article *the* before *hospital* follows US custom in this answer.

Comment: hosptialized? hospitlalized? hosiptalize? hostial stay?  -1?

Comment: @jwpat7 You let me slide on several others. My typing and proofing baldy need work. We could use a spell checker herre.

Comment: In Firefox, right click in an edit box drops a menu that includes spell check.

Answer (score 3):

You could say "hospitalizes/hospitalization" or "I'm being admitted *to* hospital" (NOT "at the").

For statistics, if you are referring only to patients, then they could be classed as "outpatient visits" ("outpatients" are patients who got to hospital for an appointment but do not take up a bed, i.e. they go in, see the doctor/nurse, and leave to go home again after their appointment.)

Patients are "admitted" to hospital overnight - "patient admissions". When they are well enough to go home they are "discharged". "Patient discharges" seems to be the appropriate term, but could suggest something else!

See http://www.biomedcentral.com/1472-6963/12/180

Comment: You apparently think something is wrong with “I’m being admitted at the hospital”.  If so, what is wrong with it?

Comment: It should be "I'm being admitted *to hospital". The verb "admit" takes the preposition "to", not "at" here. As discussed by others, the use of the definite article seems to depend on whether you speak US or British English. In the variety of English I speak (British), the definite article is not required and, indeed, sounds odd.

Comment: You assert that *admit* takes  preposition *to*, not *at*, in the example sentence.  Do you have a reference to support that assertion?

Comment: @Suke This is an old post, but I wanted to note that the phrase "being admitted to hospital" is very much alien to American English. Americans will generally put an article before hospital (admitted to *the* hospital). We would only leave out the article if hospitals was plural (e.g. "One thousand patients were admitted to hospitals around the city after the earthquake"). It's vaguely reminiscent of how British people use the word "sport". Brits talk about their love of *sport*, while Americans talk about their love of *sports*.