# Which nouns should include an article after "go to [noun]" in AmE and BE?

Tags: articles, toponyms

When referring to a non-specific instance of a place (*hospital*, *theatre*), there seems to be a strange inconsistency as to when you use *the*. Is there any sort of pattern, or is there any reference site that lists these out somewhat comprehensively?

American English:

- *go to the hospital*
- *go to school*
- *go to church*
- *go to the mall*
- *go to the theater*
- *go to the police station*
- *go to the train station*
- *go to the airport*
- *go to the supermarket*
- *go to the post office*
- *go to the market* (is *go to market* okay in American English?)
- *go to town*
- *go to college*
- *go to jail*
- *go to the bank*

British English:

- *go to hospital*
- *go to school*
- *go to church*
- *go to the theatre*
- *go to the cinema*
- ???

This question is inspired by the conversation here: [Is there a reason the British omit the article when they "go to hospital"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital)

Comment: I think the only differences between American and British here are *hospital, college, temple,* and *university*.

Answer (score 1):

This has been much debated in postings *passim*, on this site.

In Britain we only say he is 'in hospital' if 'he' is a patient. If we are talking about a doctor, nurse or other employee we say 'he/she works at the hospital'.

Similarly with schools; pupils go 'to school', but teachers work at 'the school'.

With 'church' it is slightly different. If they were attending or officiating at a service, both congregation and minister would say they were 'at church'. But if someone was polishing the pews on a weekday, they would be working at 'the church'.

In other words the dropping of the article indicates a change of meaning. If I am 'at university', it means I am a student, and university is my way of life. But if I am an electrician changing the lighting in the lecture theatres, I would be working 'at the university'.

Comment: Can you use the same principle for _go to theatre_ or _go to police station_?

Comment: @Jun-Dai No, sadly not. It’s not very consistent. You don’t _go to theatre_ at all, nor do you _go to police station_ or _go to bank_ or _go to post office_.

Comment: @Jun-DaiBates-Kobashigawa You might _go to theatre_ in a hospital, but not to see a theatrical performance.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But people do go to 'prison'. Whilst the staff work 'at the prison', or 'in a prison'.

Comment: Again, people do not 'go to penitentiary', 'go to infirmary', or 'go to academy'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But even in America, people 'go to jail'.

Comment: ....as OP said.

Comment: "But even in America, people 'go to jail'" but they don't pass 'Go' and don't collect £200 >;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But a surgeon may have certain days when he is ***in theatre***, and others *out of theatre*.