# "I saw Sue in town yesterday, but she didn't see me." Why is there no article before "town"?

Tags: articles, zero-article

From a Raymond Murphy book on English grammar, I saw the following sentence:

> I saw Sue in town yesterday, but she didn't see me.

Why is there no article before "town"?

Is the following incorrect? Why?

> I saw Sue in a/the town yesterday.

Comment: Same reason there isn't an article in "I'm going to school" or "I was in bed".

Comment: @DanBron but in BrEng you can say: "Tomorrow I'm going to the hospital"

Comment: @Mari-LouA In AmE, you *must* say "I'm going to *the* hospital". In BrE, you can say "She is in hospital".

Comment: Thank you for the speedy endorsement; however, it has only been five minutes, and there is no harm in waiting for other, potentially better answers to materialize before accepting.

Comment: @DanBron "She's in hospital" yes, but I still wouldn't say "Tomorrow I'm going to hospital" That is not idiomatic. EDIT: Maybe not...

Comment: For those of us in the country there is _going to town_ or _going into town_.

Comment: @Mari-LouA But “I'm going into hospital” and “I'm taking you to hospital” are both fine in BrE, while they're unidiomatic in AmE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In town* here uses a special sense of *town*, which refers to whatever is understood to be the local region. Saying someone is *in town* is akin to saying they are *in the neighborhood* or *in the area*; as the [LDOCE has it](http://www.ldoceonline.com/Geography-topic/town):

> **where you live** [uncountable]: the town or city where you live:
>
> > *Cam **left town** about an hour ago, so he should be out at the farm by now.
> >
> >      I'll be **out of town** for about a week.
> >
> >      Guess who's **in town**? Jodie's sister!
> >
> >      Do you know of a good place to eat? I'm from **out of town** (=from a different town).
> >
> >     We're moving to another part of town.*

- To say *Cam left town* means he departed from the local area, or from wherever area he had been before. To say *Cam left his town* means he departed from (perhaps abandoned) his hometown. To say *Cam left the town* means he departed from some particular settlement which is known.
- If you live *in town*, it means you live in the local urbanized area, as opposed to living *in the suburbs* or *in the country* for the outlying areas.
- You can be *out of the town* but not *out of town*— that is, you can be physically outside the boundary line of a jurisdiction that is called a town, but you have not left the larger area.

There are other locations— mostly institutions— where dropping the determiner changes the meaning, like being *in hospital* or *out of school*; writing *from prison* or *at sea*; or going *to church* or *to court*.

See for example *[Which nouns should include an article after "go to [noun]" in AmE and BE?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172745)* and *[Is there a reason the British omit the article when they "go to hospital"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604)*.

Answer (score 0):

For urban (and quasi-urban) dwellers "in town" means in their residential environs.  Depending on the context, it might mean in the business district.  This is opposed to "out of town," which means traveling away from home.

Comment: And for rural dwellers, it generally means in the town closest by where they live. In fact, I’d say it’s rarer for urban dwellers to use the phrase at all, since they (often) spend all their time in town, so there’s frequently not much need to specify ‘town’ generically, but more of a need to subspecify (‘downtown’, ‘at X’, ‘by X’, etc.).

Comment: For residents of large cities, "in town" doesn't distinguish between a residential area and a commercial area, since there are too many of the latter.  But a New Yorker will say to a neighbor on his way to Washington, DC, "Let's get together for a drink when you're back in town."

Comment: That’s true. I was thinking more narrowly of the example given in the question where “I saw Sue in town yesterday” almost unequivocally indicates that “I” live and am currently situated in a non-urban area outside the town in question.