# "to church" and "to the church"

Tags: differences, prepositions, definite-articles

What is the reason for using "to" and "to the" before the word "church" in different parts of this passage?

> On Sundays, we always went **to church**. After breakfast, the carriage took Ambrose and me **to the church** in the village. All the servants came **to church** too. On Sunday evenings, we had an early dinner. Usually, some of our neighbours would eat with us.

([*My Cousin Rachel*](http://english-e-reader.net/book/my-cousin-rachel-daphne-du-maurier), Daphne Du Maurie)

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. One of our minimum requirements is basic research before posting. Could you please edit to include the results of your reasearch, that is to say, beyond the source ?

Comment: related question [Is there a reason the British omit the article when they “go to hospital”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital)

Comment: Also see *[Which nouns should include an article after “go to -noun-” in AmE and BE?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172745)* and *[Is there a reason the British omit the article when they “go to hospital”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604)*

Comment: There are other nouns that can be used without an article after "to" with a special meaning. The exact list varies between dialects, but one common example is "to the school" (= "to a specific school building") vs. "to school" (to any school, to a generic school). You should see the post that  ChongDogMillionaire linked to and may also find it helpful to look through the [other posts that are linked to it](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/19604?sort=votes).

Comment: Thanks you all ... Sorry It seems that I hadn't searched well in community. I will try more the next time.

Comment: @Cascabel Sorry I did search about that but It seems that I wasn't precise in doing that. I will do better next time.

Comment: No problem , my friend. Please do not be discouraged from contributing to this site. Although your Q may appear basic to many users on this site, it has validity. This usage is different between  AmE, and BrE, but has been addressed many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By saying *to church* one means church the institution. By saying *to **the** church* one means church the building.

> On Sundays, we always went to church.

Here, it doesn't matter which church we went to, geographically. What is important is that we attended the Christian House of God.

> After breakfast, the carriage took Ambrose and me to the church in the village

Here, a specific building rather than the institution in general is meant, hence the definite article.

It is the same difference as between *to school* and *to **the** school*.