# Does "Magna Carta" require an article?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, latin

I have seen (the) Magna Carta referred to both with and without an article, a distinction that doesn't seem to have any relation to nationality (i.e. I've seen British sources and American sources both use and omit the article).

["Stop Revering Magna Carta"](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/06/15/opinion/stop-revering-magna-carta.html?ref=international)— *The New York Times*

> Through Coke’s treatises, **Magna Carta** traveled across the Atlantic. William Penn published an edition in 1687, and in the 17th century several colonies enacted **Magna Carta** as part of their law. With the Stamp Act of 1765, the imagery of a tyrannical government impinging on ancient rights proved useful to both John Adams and Benjamin Franklin, who invoked different provisions of **Magna Carta** in calling for repeal. The founding fathers thought they were drawing on the document in drafting the Constitution, for example, in the clause “due process of law” — though that phrase was added to **Magna Carta** in English law only in the 14th century.

[The Magna Carta enshrined our liberties - now we must fight for them again](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2015/jun/15/magna-carta-800-years-human-rights-act)
— *The Guardian*

> It’s because of **the Magna Carta** that, in 2003, 3 million of us were able to come together to protest against the Iraq war. It’s **the Magna Carta** that means we can legally fight cases where a severely disabled person is confined to a single room because her local council has failed to provide suitable housing. And, ironically, it’s **the Magna Carta** that has ultimately allowed us to vote in a government that seems hell bent on destroying it.

Is one usage preferred or more acceptable? Does the Latin nature of the phrase "Magna Carta" remove the normal need to attach an article?

Comment: "The" has been used for quite a long time there. (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(the+Magna+Carta)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28the%20Magna%20Carta%29%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Even [NGrams AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=before+Magna+Carta%2Cbefore+the+Magna+Carta&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbefore%20Magna%20Carta%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbefore%20the%20Magna%20Carta%3B%2Cc0) has more *without* the article. But it's [BrE usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=before+Magna+Carta%2Cbefore+the+Magna+Carta&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbefore%20Magna%20Carta%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbefore%20the%20Magna%20Carta%3B%2Cc0) that counts ('cos it's *ours!* :)

Comment: Personally, I think (as a Brit, natch) that it sounds a bit weird to include the article, but obviously an increasing number of people (particularly, *Americans*) are starting to do this. Even so, it's still very much a minority usage in BrE.

Comment: Has the possibility that some of these instances may be misleading because they are in titles where 'the' is dropped?

Comment: Without in any way disputing the thrust of the above comments, it's worth noting that the first example given _could_ just be journalese. For example a (future!) headline might well say "As Declaration Of Independence Turns 800..." even though, as far as I know, it's unambiguously _the_ Declaration of Independence.

Comment: Look in the body of the cited article @Morton— it's consistent use w/o an article

Comment: @eliyahu-g You're right - sorry.

Comment: I think you'd find the average American joe (if he has even heard of Magna Carta) *saying* "*the* Magna Carta", whereas in printed works, especially historical works, you'll find it without the article, for example, "*since* Magna Carta".  But you have to be careful with Google. For example, they seem to be including books published by Cambridge University Press (UK) among the American results.

Comment: Let's ask the BBC.  (http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/primaryhistory/british_history/magna_carta/)

Comment: I want to point out that the article usage doesn't seem to be correlated to nationality... I've included only two citations, but the American one has no article, and the British one does, and a cursory search of google news for articles on the 800th anniversary shows that there is a great deal of variation on both sides.

Comment: @eliyahu-g.  What we cannot see from these Google searches is use in speech (as distinct from writing).  I have never in my life *heard* anyone not use the definite article with *Magna Carta*. I say "American joe" because that's who I have experience with and whose speech I can attest to..

Comment: Shouldn't it be _Ye_?

Comment: Joanna Americana here - I, too, have never heard - not even once - a reference to the Magna Carta lacking the definite article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "Magna Carta" is a Latin name and Latin would not need the use of an article then it is technically improper to use the definite article with it.

However, both seem to be acceptable in normal usage.

Source: http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/112237?redirectedFrom=Magna+Carta

(may need a subscription so here is the relevant text pasted in)

"Usu. without article."

Comment: Not downvoting, but the first sentence is a line of argument with a long and rather ignominious pedigree. For instance the old "don't split an infinitive" (mis)rule supposedly came from scholars of Latin, where such a thing was not possible. The problem is that Latin and English are indisputably different languages, and we are talking about English here. It is quite proper to impose English grammar rules upon terms imported into it once they have been used in English for a while. 800 years seems long enough to me.

Comment: Also, if we were to stick to Latin grammar rules here, I believe the ending on "Carta" would have to change depending on what part of a sentence it is being used in. I got D's in Latin though, so don't hold me to that...

Comment: Fair point, the naturalisation (over 800 years) is probably the reason why it is quite common to see it both with and without the definite article. As with many things (see: Oxford comma) I suppose it is just a matter of style, and consistency is key.

Comment: You have also reminded me of the maxim: "Happy is the man who has never been told to not split the infinitive." ;)

Comment: There's a difference between using Latin rules with Latin (including Latin quotations and set phrases) and using Latin rules with English (as in split infinitives). Most people would accept that Latin spelling is a good guide to spelling Latin words in English (give or take a suffix). Other rules are interpreted differently: you certainly hear a lot of non-Latin plurals of Latin expressions: bona fides, agendas, discuses, radiuses. Latin words often have a different meaning in English, e.g. a narrower legal meaning, or as with bona fide. And it's common to say The Aeneid.

Answer (score 4):

The funny thing about the definite article is that it is used differently in America (AmE) than in England (BrE). In general, I believe BrE has a tendency to drop it, where AmE has a tendency to insert it.

The most famous example is the word [Hospital](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital). In the US, a person goes "to *the* hospital", while in the UK one goes "to hospital". I'm gathering that "Magna Carta" is also in this boat.

To my American eyes, using it without "the" just looks wrong. I'd be tempted to think either the writer is referring to some other "great charter" (that's what the Latin translates to), or that they are being disrespectful.

So basically, I think you'll have to figure out which group is your primary audience, and accept that you are going to tick off the other. :-)

Comment: As someone who on occasion designs (computer) languages, I actually have a lot of admiration for the Brit's attempts to do away with the indefinite article. Its a nigh-useless bit of syntactic sugar.

Comment: I think you're making a false distinction here.  Look at my citations: the New York Times (American) drops the article (this is a consistent usage in all their recent articles on MC), and the Guardian (British) keeps it, suggesting the reasoning is wrong.

Comment: I think I confused things by arguing about university/college/school while also arguing for being allowed to say *the* Magna Carta.  So, (1) In the UK, we might say "He's in hospital" [no article, not specifying *which* hospital] or "I went to the hospital this morning" [meaning my local hospital.  We'd always say "She's in college/university" with no article, or "She's at Durham University" [it's its title, so no article needed anyway]. (2) I stand by "the Magna Carta".  Last month I visited *the* Alhambra in Andalusia, although "Al" is the Arabic definite article.

Comment: @eliyahu-g - I'm sorry, but that usage just looks *wrong* to me. I looked up the author of that NYT piece, and it is a professor of *International* Studies, who has spent a large part of [his CV](http://www.law.uchicago.edu/node/533/cv) outside of the US. Which dialect of English is his native one (if any) I could not tell you.

Comment: @T.E.D. the usage is in all NyTimes articles on the MC, suggesting a style choice by the paper.

Comment: c.f. http://www.nytimes.com/2015/06/15/world/europe/magna-carta-still-posing-a-challenge-at-800.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&module=second-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news

Comment: http://www.nytimes.com/2015/06/16/world/europe/magna-carta-anniversary-celebrations.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&module=second-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news

Comment: http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/06/15/world/europe/15magna-carta-quiz.html

Comment: http://www.nytimes.com/2015/03/19/arts/artsspecial/in-magna-carta-law-liberty-legacy-a-document-resonates.html

Comment: @T.E.D. I agree the usage looks wrong, but the fact that the American paper of record has so consistently used it suggests that it has some backing

Comment: For comparison, some more British citations with the article. (Though as I said, there are plenty of UK cites w/o the article): http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2012/may/27/forget-queens-jubilee-kneesup-magna-carta, http://www.yvetteforlabour.co.uk/magna_carta_david_cameron, http://www.theguardian.com/childrens-books-site/2015/jun/15/magna-carta-800-years-guide, http://www.bbc.co.uk/newsround/33110890

Comment: I think you all are right about the "University" thing. We say it different, but not at all in the simple way I'm implying. Removing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24837/discussion-between-t-e-d-and-eliyahu-g).

Comment: @eliyahu-g: On scrolling through *all* results for ["since **the** magna carta"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com%2F+%22magna+carta%22+-%22the+magna+carta%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl#q=site:http://www.theguardian.com/+%22since+the+magna+carta%22&hl=en&start=30) on the Guardian website, I find the initial estimated 130 turns out to be actually 32 instances in total.

Comment: ...whereas the initial estimate for ["since magna carta"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com%2F+%22magna+carta%22+-%22the+magna+carta%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl#q=site:http://www.theguardian.com/+%22since+magna+carta%22&hl=en&start=30) without the article is only 51, but when I scroll to the end there are actually **46**. It's *almost* six of one and half-a-dozen of the other, but I'm in no doubt that taking *British* usage as a whole the article is significantly less likely to be present.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Interesting.  I think the origin of the omitted article is British, but I think the question hinges on why the article is dropped (general UK penchant for article dropping, or historical grammatical reasons regarding Latin loan words), and I am totally unqualified to answer that question.

Comment: @eliyahu-g: I find your perspective strange (talking about the "origin" of the omitted article). The article was never there in the first place, so what you should be asking about is the origin of the practice of *including* the article. Which NGrams clearly indicates is primarily an AmE C20 usage - but almost certainly BrE will eventually fall into line, simply because AmE dominates the language by sheer weight of numbers in most contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've seen several British uses of the article from the 19th century: https://www.google.com/search?q=magna+carta&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=magna+carta&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899 Though obviously that gives me no idea about prevalence

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ngrams gives me very similar results for both US and UK up until 1960, but both show similar trend https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+Magna+Carta%2Con+the+Magna+Carta&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20Magna%20Carta%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20Magna%20Carta%3B%2Cc0 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+Magna+Carta%2Con+the+Magna+Carta&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20Magna%20Carta%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20Magna%20Carta%3B%2Cc0

Comment: ... and could I also suggest: "*the* Magna Carta" because you're really saying "the document formerly known as Magna Carta"?

Comment: @David Garner: I don't think there could possibly be enough such "false positive" matches to affect the overall situation, which is accurately illustrated by a claimed 148 hits for [founded on magna carta](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22founded+on+magna+carta%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Although there are only actually 31 if you scroll to the end, that's far more than the **5** for the same with an article (all relatively recent, and at least one of which is clearly from a non-native speaker).

Comment: I'm late to the party here, but just to add one thing: I'm British, and although I completely agree that it's common for us to omit the "the" in this case, _it is also anomalous_. I can't think of any other example where we refer to a historical document like that - it's _the_ Mappa Mundi, _the_ Book of Kells, _the_ Declaration of Arbroath, and so on. So I think that any attempt to fit it into a general pattern, a la "go to [the] hospital", is doomed to failure. Sorry :-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think your comment to me was misdirected.  This has gotten very confusing: one of my previous comments ["I think I confused things..."] makes no sense [you may think it never did ...] because someone deleted my comment preceding that one  -  don't know why.

Comment: @David: I was only addressing my comment to your immediately preceding one. But as it happens I just watched the BBC news item covering today's 800th anniversary celebrations. I mentioned this ELU question to the two others watching with me, so we all paid close attention. Out of a couple of dozen usages, we noticed only two with the article. One we agreed sounded perfectly natural - context *...when King John signed **the** Magna Carta*, which we felt was okay *because* it was referring to ***the** actual document*. The other (no special context) just sounded slightly "odd" to all of us.

Comment: It occurred to me tonight that grammatically, _Magna Carta_ without the article works in an equivalent way to _independence_. So we talk about _before Magna Carta_ (cf. _before independence_), _the anniversary of Magna Carta_ (cf. _the anniversary of independence_), and so on. And Magna Carta _is_ to us a little bit like independence is to other countries - a fundamental change; the foundation of our current state. Is that what underpins it all, somehow? That the words have come to stand for the situation resulting from the document, rather than the document itself?

Comment: Good point, @Morton.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I wasn't interested in usage-counts anyway.  I just wanted to disagree with the notion that, because Latin didn't have articles, we should skip them when using a borrowed Latin word or expression.

Comment: @David: oic. At the time I wasn't interested in the *origin/rationale* of the usage - simply citing figures to disabuse those who seemed to be questioning the extent to which "standard" usage today (in the UK at least) still doesn't normally include the article. Now I *am* thinking about it, I don't see Latin as particularly relevant either. But maybe there are elements of reverence (theists worship *God*, not ***the** God*) and/or "clannish" affectionate familiarity (referencing *Mother, Father* when speaking to others outside the family).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, oic too.  *Just* to be mischievous, Muslims worship 'Al-lah'  -  *the* God!

Comment: @David: And Google Books estimates about 2,950,000 results for written instances of [***the** god of abraham*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+god+of+abraham%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). So far as I can make out, everyone except the Jews, Christians, and Muslims agrees all three worship "the same" god, but I don't think that necessarily argues in favour of syntactic consistency. We can say that the ancient egyptians worshipped [*Ra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra) or that they worshipped ***the** sun*, but never ***the** Ra*.

Comment: ... actually, putting real fanatics aside, don't the Jews, Christians and Muslims themselves agree that they worship the same god?  'People of the Book', 'Children of Abraham', etc.  We've drifted away from English usage, so I'll stop there.

Answer (score 3):

First a baldly stated answer:

> In AmE, it is '**the** Magna Carta', spoken or written, but headlines may drop the article as they usually do.

Now commentary:
I wondered what the ballyhoo here was about (the) Magna Carta until I heard on the news today about it's 800th anniversary... from the BBC... in which the announcer talked about 'Magna Carta'. And, I, as an AmE speaker, thought that was jarring. To my ears it definitely needs an article.

That said, this shows the difficulty in making pronouncements. Maybe the announcer (or copy editor) is weird. Maybe I'm weird, maybe the professor in the interview is weird, maybe you're weird (weird = out of the ordinary). Maybe the corpora are skewed/selected weird/use headlines mostly, etc. etc. etc. And maybe 'ordinary' is very context dependent.

And it seems like all the data that's been gathered so far (Google NGrams/COCA/BNC) is inconsistent. So all I have to go on is the dreaded introspection.

Comment: I'd suggest taking the chat link in the comments of my answer and reading it over. @eliyahu-g Has indeed found tons of examples from US-based publications of an article-less Magna Carta. There's even one intriguing example where someone at CNN seems to have missed an edit and left one occurrence of the article in. I regretfully have to agree with him that this looks like a concerted effort.

Comment: (otherwise, this is essentially making the same point as my answer, so +1 from me. :-)   )

Comment: @T.E.D. Yes. My point was that all this data you've collected seems to go against yours and my personal (though limited) experience... but I feel like our experience should take precedence here. Or maybe we (and many others) are making a systematic error that editors have been trying to battle aagainst for years.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the use of "Magna Carta" is a historical convention. However, like most historical conventions, it is being forgotten and the default treatment is being applied, making it "the Magna Carta".

I am not sure of the rationale of that convention, but it is notable that "Magna Carta" is a name that only attached to the document(s) much later, and in any event the original (1215) Magna Carta was swiftly set aside by the Pope and the Magna Carta which had legal force (and different wording) did not exist until 1255 when Henry III was old enough to sign it. So perhaps calling it "the" Magna Carta when you're talking about a legal document issued and reissued in many copies and versions over 40-odd years makes no sense. It's not a single document ("the MC"), it's not part of a group ("a MC"), it's just a class of things called Magna Carta.

Answer (score 1):

The OED says of "Magna Carta": "*Usually without article*."

It has two definitions - it can refer to the "*charter of English personal and political liberty*", and in this sense, none of the OED's nine citations have the definite article (though one of them has the determiner "his") - or it can refer to "*any similar document*", and in this sense, some of them do have the article.

Some proper nouns are preceded by an article and others aren't (and some common names such as "parliament" gain a capital and often drop their article when referring to the actions of the British Parliament: "Parliament has decided ...").  The other "great charters" are all referred to with the definite article.  So it is at least possible that the fact that "Carta" isn't an English word, and the fact that "Magna Carta" is a proper noun made up entirely of foreign words, may have discouraged the use of "the" historically.  It is difficult to think of another great historical document or charter that is named in English without using a definite article, but it is also difficult to think of another one with a comparable name.