# Article 'a' or 'the'

Tags: articles

Is it wrong to say "I work at a hospital" if I mean that I work in a specific hospital unknown to the person I am talking to? How is it different from the more common "I work at the hospital"?

Comment: Both are valid for me, but they mean different things. The first means that I work at some unspecified hospital, more specifically that the kind of place I work at could be described as a hospital. The second implies there's some local or known hospital that people work at, and that's where I work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a reason the British omit the article when they "go to hospital"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not wrong. It's the same with this "a" or "the" as it is with any other. "I work at a hospital" means you are not volunteering the specific hospital at which you work. "I work at the hospital" says you are referring to a specific hospital, and that there is only one hospital to which the listener could reasonably assume you are referring.

Hopefully you will consider my response **the** answer, and not just **an** answer... :-)

Comment: LOL good! And my pleasure

Comment: But there is a potential confusion because in US English they say "in the hospital" to mean "as a patient in a hospital" without necessarily implying a particular hospital. This is not directly relevant to the question because it does not apply to **working** in the hospital; but it is a potential confusing factor. In British English we say "in hospital" for that.