# To university or to the university

Tags: definite-articles

Is better to say "to university" or "to the university"?
I have this doubt.

Comment: Please provide context. An example sentence. Also, whether you are asking about British or American English. We have previous questions covering this. Such as [Is there a reason the British omit the article when they “go to hospital”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital)

Comment: You've provided no context whatsoever, so no answer is really possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on context.

*I am going to university.*
This indicates a student currently enrolled in some kind of class or program at a university.

*I am going to* the *university.* This indicates the person is travelling to the campus of the university.

Comment: Anybody care to provide me a clue why you down-voted this answer?