# Why do we say "I'm at home", but "I'm at the gym" instead of "I'm at gym"?

Tags: grammar

I was speaking to some ELL and they asked me the above question and I wasn't able to give a good answer.

What's the reason we need to prefix gym with "the", but not do the same for places like home, or school, or work?

Comment: It probably has something to do with the fact that “home” is a unique place, while “the gym” signify either a specific gym or represents a function (a place where you work out). You can say “I'm at the school” if the school mentioned is not unique.

Comment: We say I’m at home, school, work, lunch; but at the house, at the office, at the restaurant.

Comment: The best explanation is probably that idiomatic expressions don't follow patterns.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I think there’s too much reliance on the specificity criterion, too much effort to cram hard cases into poor rules; although I think calling the hard cases idioms is better than cramming.

Comment: I think it's more that there are a number of gyms, so you need to specify you are going to **the** gym. There's only one home. Although You could probably leave a note that said **Gone to Gym, back in 30 minutes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of idiomatic expression, particularly in American English. But, it relies upon the specificity of the location in question.

British English has more examples of places that don't require a definite article.  [See this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-there-a-reason-the-british-omit-the-article-when-they-go-to-hospital)

As a rule, home without an article usually defines a specific location. That is, *my home*. If you were at a friend's house you'd say *the home of a friend*.  (Ironically, you'd still say I'm at *the house* even when it's yours ....)

The same applies to school. I'm at *school* means I'm at the school I always attend. I'm at *the school* implies that it's not a habitual location for you.

The same applies to Nome, Alaska. I'm in *Nome, Alaska*. Not *the Nome, Alaska*. So, it seems to hinge (in AmE) on the specificity of the location.